# How to use C# IList<> in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, mscorlib

I am trying to make an Asp.NET Core MVC project with Web API.
There is a model that has a list of items: `IList<Item>`.

I get the following error:

> cs0012 The type `IList<>` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>       You must add a reference to the assembly mscorlib, version 4.0.0.0, ...

How do I fix this? - any suggestions

Comment: Please show your project file. It sounds like you've got a very odd project problem - it's not going to be `IList<T>`-specific...

Comment: I'm assuming you have run `dotnet restore` to make sure all the packages are available?